# Title within subsection

Tags: titles, subsection

I'm writing about 4 mathematical methods for performing an operation, and I need titles within the subsection like Method 1: Description of method. Obviously these do not go in the index, and I don't want it to be numbered. Eg. no 4.3.2.

I just need to add something like I would in Word, bold text in appropriate size introducing a method, within a subsection.

How do I do this?

Comment: Use the optional argument for `\subsection[<ToC entry>]{<Body entry>}`.

Comment: Hi, that would make it a numbered section. I don't want it to be numbered, how do I do that?

Comment: I just need to add something like I would in Word, bold text introducing a method, within a subsection.

Comment: `\subsection*{Title}` produces a subsection with `Title` as a heading which is not numbered or added to the table of contents

Comment: as an alternative to section you could use a description list `\begin{description} \item[some method] ....  \item[another method] ...\end{description}`

Comment: If it's *within* a `\subsection`, then `\subsubsection{Method 1: Description of method}` with `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` in the preamble (which will only number/insert sectional units up to `\subsection` (level 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a section/subsection/subsubsection etc. without a number using the starred version of the normal command.
You want a title within the subsection, so this suggests a subsubsection. You can get an un-numbered subsubsection with

```
\subsubsection*{Title}
```

replacing `Title` with whatever you want as the heading.

A full example would be

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{This is a numbered section}
\subsection{This is a numbered subsection}
\subsubsection*{This is an un-numbered subsubsection}
\subsubsection{This is a numbered subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]